# Can cassandra datacenters configured to replication receiver only?

Tags: cassandra

Assuming that we have 2 cassandra datacenters.
One of them is **productive environment** and well-secured, the other one is a **test environment** and easier to break, hence **non-trusted**.

We want data replication, but only propagated from the productive environment to test environment, not vice versa.

Is there any way to configure one **data-center as a slave**: not to receive replication data from the other one, and to revert the untrusted changes? It should be a read-only instance, which only receives data from the other datacenter.

In case somebody breaks the test environment, we do not want to productive environment to receive any manipulated data. Target would be that the test environment changes get reverted to the productive environment during replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible directly - in Cassandra changes made to the keyspace are propagated to all sides.

You can try different options by using separate clusters for prod and test:

- Implement code to read [CDC files](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/operating/cdc.html), and apply to test cluster - this won't help with deleting the data from test environment, as this approach only apply changes.
- Use [DataStax advanced replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/advRepTOC.html) (that uses similar approach)
- periodically replay the data from production to test using [SSTableLoader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader.html) - it will replay all data, so it will help with deletion of data on test. But it could take quite a long time if you have a lot of data.